# Fastify - TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, typeerror, fastify

When i created a new API with fastify, while testing it, it was throwing

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

      at next (node_modules/fastify/lib/route.js:407:32)
      at preParsingHookRunner (node_modules/fastify/lib/route.js:438:3)
      at runPreParsing (node_modules/fastify/lib/route.js:389:5)
      at Object.routeHandler [as handler] (node_modules/fastify/lib/route.js:349:7)
      at Router.lookup (node_modules/find-my-way/index.js:356:14)
```

The control doesn't even pass to the routes and when i checked the file mentioned in the stack trace, it seems to be related with preParser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was apparently a JSON Schema issue.

In one of the routes, I had the schema like this,

```
{
  type: "object",
  required: ["fileType"],
  properties: {
    fileType: {
      type: {
         type: "string",
         enum: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "all"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which is wrong, and it should be,

```
{
  type: "object",
  required: ["fileType"],
  properties: {
    fileType: {
      type: "string",
      enum: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "all"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Able to find this in GitHub issues, and someone had the same issue with JSON Schema. Fastify sometimes doesn't throw any error if the schema is wrong which is the reason why it became unnoticed. https://github.com/fastify/help/issues/424

Answer (score 0):

The error message specifically indicates that the property length is being called on an undefined value. This could be due to an issue with the data being passed to the preParsing hook, or a problem with the code inside the hook itself.